# How to include Chrome Driver in executable Jar file when I export my tests to a Executable jar

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to export my test case into an executable jar so that I can run them any where or from any machine, but I got the problem of Chrom Driver is not set by the system.properity. I need a solution where I can export my code into executable jar and include Chrome Drivre so that it could run on any machine even it doesn't have Chrome Drivre on it.

I tried to include Chrome Driver on environment variables and Selenium Path.
I also tried to add Chrome Driver under project resources but nothing worked.

```
            public WebDriver OpenCPURL()  {


    PropertyConfigurator.configure("Log4j.properties");
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  
            "./chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    //driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //driver.manage().window().maximize();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    baseUrl = "http://3ddxtesting/newcp/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    user_name = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
    Pass = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    user_name.sendKeys(username);
    Log.info(username);
    Pass.sendKeys(Password);
    WebElement LoginButton = driver
            .findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"contentDiv\"]/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]/input"));
    LoginButton.click();
    String Pageheader = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#body > nav > a > font")).getText();
    assertEquals(Pageheader, "3D | Diagnostix");

    return driver;

}
```

And here I call this method:

public class Add_3D_Printers_Order {

```
CommonLogin Login = new CommonLogin();
WebDriver driver = Login.OpenCPURL();
 driver.findElement(By.id("printerCheck")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    String Pageheader_printer = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#locationId")).getText();
    assertEquals(Pageheader_printer, "Add Order > Printer & Acc");
    System.out.println("the assertion is done and the application navigate to the 3d printer page");
    Log.info("the application navigate to the 3d printer page succssfully");
```

This code runs wherever any machine has the Chrome driver on the same path but on other machines it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can make a folder in your project with a name driver and can insert your chromedriver in that folder and you can pick the chromedriver from that location using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

For example, use this line of code after making a folder named `driver` and then adding `chromedriver` in it:
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/driver/chromedriver");`

Here `System.getProperty("user.dir")` would give you the project directory path and then appending it with `/driver/chromedriver` would give you the exact path of the chromedriver and then it could be used in any machine.

Comment: I already tried this solution before but when I extract the test to an executable jar and run it on a machine that doesn't have the chrome driver, I got the error can not find chrome driver in this path

Comment: The OS on which you coded and the OS on which you are running the script are same ?

Comment: Yes it is Windows 10 on both